# Start / Stop MongoDB with Homebrew

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I am using mac osx 10.10.5

This question has been asked many times before and after following the steps, I notice bizarre behavior.

These are the steps which I have taken

```
brew tap gapple/services
brew install mongodb
```

This installs the product and now when I do `brew services list` I can see mongodb in a stopped state.

When I tried to start the process by `brew services start mongodb` I get an error

Error: Could not read the plist for `mongodb`!

OK. I googled a solution

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.6/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Now as soon as the file is copied, when I do `brew services list` ... the mongo process is automatically running.

Now when I do `brew services stop mongodb`
It says

```
Error: Service `mongodb` not running, wanna start it? Try `brew services start mongodb`
```

Now this is bizarre, because just in the last step it said its running. Now when I do

`mongodb services list` it says that the service is stopped. (so the stop command above did work. Even though it threw an error).

Now if I do

```
brew services start mongodb
```

It gives error Error: Could not read the plist for `mongodb`!

Now if I copy the file again

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.6/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

The service automatically begins to run.

I find this whole thing really bizarre. All I want is a clean way to start stop the mongo db service. And although there are many threads on this site (and elsewhere) ... they don't work or just have strange behavior.

Comment: run brew services list to check the mongodb installed package

Answer (score 34):

```
brew services start/restart/stop mongodb-community@4.0
```

Answer (score 17):

For me I had multiple version of mongodb and when I tried to switching between them, I got this error

```
Error: Could not read the plist for `mongodb26`!
```

This is what I did to start mongodb26 service.

```
brew unlink mongodb24
brew link mongodb26
brew services start mongodb26
```

Answer (score 15):

You can list services by doing 
`brew services list`
and then as one of the answers said `brew services start [NAME]` or `brew services stop [NAME]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at their [Github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services) repo on this. I **gapple/services** is deprecated. This might be a more up to date options.

Answer (score 1):

You should use instead: `brew services stop mongodb-community@4.2`, don't forget to mention the version of MongoDB you installed and using for your purposes.

If you still facing issues, follow this link: [Click here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/brew+stop+mongodb+server)

Answer (score 0):

I personally run

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

(When running only "brew services start mongodb"  I am provided with an error message)

Answer (score -1):

inside of Hombrew Simple way is to get the process id of MongoDB and kill it.
get the pid:

```
pgrep mongo
```

then kill with this command

```
kill <pid>
```

Comment: the question was about brew: `brew services stop mongodb-community`