# Is there a way to resolve this MongoDB error on M1 Mac?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I run `mongosh` from the terminal, the following error message is showing up:

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 63622a3e44b4f06269433548
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

What can be done to resolve it?

I tried reinstalling MongoDB multiple times through homebrew. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: is the mongo daemon running?

Comment: yes. It's running.

Comment: what happens when you type `mongo`

Comment: zsh: command not found: mongo

Comment: that error is being displayed

Comment: yeah idk i am on linux but i usually see that error if mongod is not running

Comment: I stopped mongod and tried to run it again

Comment: another error is showing up and its preventing it from running.

Comment: Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/danithomas/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974639/start-stop-mongodb-with-homebrew

Comment: I tried this solution, but the same error is happening.

Comment: try remove this parameter from the url: `serverSelectionTimeoutMS=200`

Comment: so i just did it on my m1 macbook (work) and it worked fine for me following these instructions: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions on my M1 and it worked fine. I think you didn't start mongod correctly:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew update
brew install mongodb-community@6.0 mongosh
mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf
```

install with brew and start mongod manually. There's a message after you install that shows you how to make it start when you boot up and login.

```
To start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community now and restart at login:
  brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf
```